# Google Map V2 Blank screen

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragmentactivity, android-maps-v2

I'm currently developing an application using the Galaxy S3 with Android version 4.0, Ice Cream Sandwich. I followed [Vogella's tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html) on how to use Google Map v2 for Android to create a sample map and it worked on Ice Cream Sandwich. Shows everything on the map. However when I try to access application's map activity on my friends Android device with version 2.3 Gingerbread I gets a blank screen with only the GPS button and zoom in and out button visible but on my phone it's running perfectly fine.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.barcodelibrary"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.mapApp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapApp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP" >
</uses-permission>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mapApp.HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.example.mapApp.MyMap" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="MY API KEY" />
</application>
```

Layout:

```
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Activity:

```
public class MyMap extends FragmentActivity{
private GoogleMap map;
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    SupportMapFragment FMap = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    map = FMap
}}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You actually wrote that you made the changes which were suggested, but you had still problems... could you let us know, which was the last error message you received

Comment: I've edited the question and my activity code as now I'm not getting a force close anymore but a blank screen with no error messages when running on Gingerbread.

Comment: Do you have a valid or correct map api key? Post your entire manifest file not just a portion of it.

Comment: Yep I'm using a valid key as I am able to access the map activity without any problems on my device version ICS.

Comment: Post your entire manifest file, the problem is probably there.

Comment: I've posted my manifest file

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="my api key" />
```

needs to be inside application tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your Manifest Must be like Below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
   package="com.djandroid.mapsv2"  
   android:versionCode="1"  
   android:versionName="1.0" >  
   <uses-sdk  
     android:minSdkVersion="8"  
     android:targetSdkVersion="16" />  
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />  
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />  
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />  
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />  
   <uses-permission android:name="com.djandroid.mapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />  
   <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />  
   <uses-feature  
     android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"  
     android:required="true" />  
   <application  
     android:allowBackup="true"  
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"  
     android:label="@string/app_name"  
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >  
     <activity  
       android:name="com.djandroid.mapsv2.MainActivity"  
       android:label="@string/app_name" >  
       <intent-filter>  
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />  
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />  
       </intent-filter>  
     </activity>  
     <meta-data  
       android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"  
       android:value="API_KEY" />  
     <uses-library  
       android:name="com.google.android.maps"  
       android:required="true" />  
   </application>  
 </manifest>
```

You are forgate this in your manifest file :

```
<uses-feature  
     android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"  
     android:required="true" />
```

thats Why you may get below error in log:

```
Then error is : java.lang.RuntimeException: Google Maps Android API only supports OpenGL ES 2.0 andabove. Please add <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" /> into AndroidManifest.xml
```

For Full Code [ClickHere](http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-google-map-v2-part-1.html)